# How to process PointCloud2 message data in python?

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to save a pointcloud data using python. Bu I haven't been able to import pcl.
I am no sure if my installation in  correct as I keep getting this error : `ImportError: No module named pcl`

How do I save the point cloud data using python

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255450/how-to-process-pointcloud2-message-data-in-python?/) by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2017-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no (official) `pcl` package for Python afaik, so that won't work. You can try and see whether [strawlab/python-pcl](https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl) can do what you want, but it appears not to have been kept up-to-date with PCL.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on 2017-02-23**:
Thank you @gvdhoorn for your reply. Can you please tell me how to install python-pcl from strawlab. I did a git clone from their repo to my working directory. I then in my py script said , "import pcl", it wouldn't wok giving the error mentioned above in my question.

Thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-23**:
That is really more of a Python question than a ROS one. Check whether [Installing Packages - Installing from a local src tree](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#installing-from-a-local-src-tree) helps.